Long Processing Telegram API Event Using Telethon Library
I wrote this message edit event handler for printing the content of edited message (from public tg channel) right to my console and then putting it in chatgpt prompt through g4f library for getting an answer for a riddle that's in telegram message, but this isn't working properly. The main problem here is that when i'm using this event handler for my local channel with no subscribers and readers it works completely OK, but when i try to use it with the big one i'm having delay from 1 to 10 seconds - right before initial code starts running.
g4f query seems to be ok as you can see it in this console output:
16:33:25.315 | check
16:33:25.315 | >>> Riddle: What was the name of the ruler in ancient Egypt?
16:33:26.177 | Answer: Pharaoh
But the problem is, message was edited at 16:33:14 and code starts running at 16:33:25.
Script's code:
import g4f
import g4f.Provider
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import re
from colorama import Fore, Style, init
from datetime import datetime


init(autoreset=True)

api_id = 'someid'
api_hash = 'somehash'
source_channel = 'somechannel'
pattern = r'Riddle:'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

password_pattern = r'Riddle: \s*-\s*([\s\S]+?)\n\n'

def get_current_time():
    return datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]

async def ask_g4f(question):
    try:
        prompt = f"Give an answer for this riddle in 1 word: {question}"
        response = g4f.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            provider=g4f.Provider.Ai4Chat,
            messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
            stream=False,
        )
        if isinstance(response, dict):
            return response.get('choices', [{}])[0].get('message', {}).get('content', '').strip()
        return response.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{get_current_time()} | Error: {e}")
        return None
    

@client.on(events.MessageEdited(chats=source_channel, pattern=pattern))
async def message_handler(event):
    print(f'{get_current_time()} | check')
    updated_text = event.message.message
    
    password_match = re.search(password_pattern, updated_text)
    if not password_match:
        return
    else:
        password = password_match.group(1).strip()
        print(f'{get_current_time()} | {Fore.RED}>>> Riddle: {password}') 
        answer = await ask_g4f(password)
        if answer and answer[-1] in {'.', '!', '?'}:
            answer = answer[:-1]
        if answer:
            print(f'{get_current_time()} | {Fore.YELLOW}Answer: {answer.capitalize()}')
            await client.send_message('@someuser', f'{answer.capitalize()}')
        

async def main():
    await client.start()
    
    print(f'{get_current_time()} | Client started...')
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())    

For the record, my friend uses this exact script and has no troubles. I can't truly understand what's the problem here. My local network seems to be OK, I have no troubles with Internet, I even close every side program from computer to let this script work without obstacles. Nevertheless, it can work good, without delay, but that's in 2 out of 10 cases. Is there any Telegram API and Telethon library experts? How do i get rid from this delay forever and have this event handler work instantly? Thank you in advance.

"How do i get rid from this delay forever and have this event handler work instantly?" You can't. Ultimately, it's Telegram deciding when to deliver the updates to each client.
